# I cant get a custom field for some categories

Tags: custom-options, category-products

In the category view I have a field "banner_image", for some categories it is included in the collection, and for others not, I have 3 stores, and I've tried assign the image for all sites, but didn't works. I've checked many times and all seems to be ok. I've reindexed. cleared cache. maybe I have overlooked something else ?

[image]

Comment: what is the code you are using to get the custom field??

Comment: Please check flat table enabled or not. if its enabled then try to disable and check. If its working fine then its reindexing issue nothing else.

Comment: is enabled, I deleted the flat tables and reindexed again. the banners shown in the site only when in the main site scope exist some banner too. whatever, the banner shown is the particular site assigned, not the main site banner, so I don't understand why this happened